# Model.set() with new and undefined values in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I would like to save calls to my server, so I am currently using `Model.save()` with the `patch` option and sending `changedAttributes()`.

I would like to remove an attribute and add a new one. `Model.set()`/`unset()` will modify `changedAttributes()` each time such that I cannot use it with the `Model.save()`/`patch` scheme described above.

I think I would like to simply call `Model.set()` and pass in an object with the values I wish to unset set to `undefined` along with the values I wish to set.

Is there a way that I can `unset()` and `set()` in one go to get the `changedAttributes()`? Or maybe determine the `changedAttributes()` for a combined set of operations?

```
// Currently
var m = new Backbone.Model({ "foo": "bar" });
m.unset("foo");
console.log(m.changedAttributes()); // { "foo": undefined }
m.set("baz", "bar");
console.log(m.changedAttributes()); // { "baz": "bar" }
console.log(m.attributes); // { "baz": "bar" }

// At this point, how do I get the combination of changed attributes? something like: { "foo": undefined, "baz": "bar" }?
// Is that even possible? Am I doing something horribly wrong?

//================================================================

// What (I think) I want is for Model.set() to remove attributes with values of undefined, so I only have to make one call and changedAttributes() will be pristine. Maybe with a option or something?
var w = new Backbone.Model({ "foo": "bar" });
w.set({ "foo": undefined, "baz": "bar" });
console.log(w.changedAttributes()); // { "foo": undefined, "baz": "bar" }
console.log(w.attributes); // I would like it to be { "baz": "bar" }, "foo" having been removed in the set() call.

//================================================================

// I was trying to avoid processing the objects by hand. I realize that I can do something like the following.
var h = new Backbone.Model({ "foo": "bar" });
var changes = { "foo": undefined, "baz": "bar" };
_.each(changes, function(val, key) {
    if (_.isUndefined(val)) {
        h.unset(key, { "silent": true });
    } else {
        h.set(key, val, { "silent": true });
    }
});
h.trigger('change'); // Trigger a change event after all the changes have been done.
console.log(changes); // { "foo": undefined, "baz": "bar" }
console.log(h.attributes); // { "baz": "bar" }
```

Fiddle of above code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/clayzermk1/AmBfh/

There seems to have been some discussion on this topic about a year ago https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/879. It seems like the functionality I wanted existed at some point.

**EDIT:** As @dennis-rongo pointed out, I can obviously do this by hand. To restate my question above: **"Does Backbone allow setting/deleting of attributes at once?" and if not, what is the rationale behind that decision?** Derick Bailey created Backbone.Memento (https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.memento) to deal with attribute states, and there are several issues on Backbone about model states closely related to this scenario (https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/2360, somewhat relevant: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2316, highly relevant: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2301).

**EDIT 2:** I'm not looking for a hand-rolled solution, I can *make* it do more or less what I want (see sample code above). **I'm looking for a justification of the current design with a clean example for this common scenario - set and unset in one go.**

**UPDATE:** There has been some conversation about this subject in https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2301. I have submitted a pull request (https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/2368) to try and encourage discussion of the current implementation.

Thank you to everyone who posted an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation will allow you to call `set()` and pass in an object with mixed attributes to set and unset. To effectively unset an attribute, assign it the value of `undefined`. The key will remain in the `attributes` hash on the model, but any time the model is serialized to JSON, the `undefined` values will not be present in the serialization (this is due to the implementation of `JSON.stringify()`). It will not `delete` the attributes from the model.

The behavior of `JSON.stringify()` removing `undefined` values in serialization is described on [MDN - JSON - stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description):

> If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

I was not using JSON serialization for my specific case (BSON), so I ended up having to hand-code a solution for myself.

I struck up a discussion on GitHub with a pull request, in the end a decision was made to keep the API as it is. For details see this pull requtest: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/2368.

Thank you again to everyone who participated in the discussion, both on SO and GH.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to skin this one! So, I'll focus on your the part of your question where you ask:

> Is there a way that I can `unset()` and `set()` in one go to get the `changedAttributes()`?

because I think that's the way to go here.

`Backbone.Model.unset()` is just an alias for `Backbone.Model.set()`. From the source:

```
unset: function(attr, options) {
  return this.set(attr, void 0, _.extend({}, options, {unset: true}));
},
```

So why not just do `m.set({"baz": "bar", "foo": void 0});`? See this fiddle I forked from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/dimadima/Q8ZuV/. Pasting from there, the result will be

```
console.log(m.changedAttributes()); // { "baz": "bar", "foo": undefined }
console.log(m.attributes); // // {foo: undefined, baz: "bar"}, unfortunately "foo"is not deleted
```

So `m.attributes` is a bit off because the key you've unset hasn't been *deleted*, but you can test for that.

Anyway, I recommend skimming the source of `Backbone.Model.set()` to get a sense of what your other options would be. I could elaborate if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer dimadima. I'd examined the source for `set()` previously and noted the `unset()` alias / `{ unset: true }` flag in `set()`. `void 0` evaluates to `undefined` so functionally, I don't think that is any different than what I'm doing in my "What I want" example. I also need for the attribute to be deleted entirely (having `undefined` values causes issues elsewhere).

Comment: So, that being the case, I would define my own `.set()` that's just an `_.wrap`per around `Backbone.Model.set`: calls `Backbone.Model.set` (see "Brief aside on super" at http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend), but afterward also does something like Dennis suggests. Then you could call your `set()` using the object notation, and it would also remove the undefined values.

Comment: Simply put, if you look at the source for `Backbone.model.set`, you'll see that `this.changed` is reset every time you call `.set`, and  `.changedAttributes` relies on `this.changed`. So you need to use the object form of `.set` unless you want to devise some way to keep track of changes yourself as they accumulate between calls.

Comment: Thank you. I had considered overriding the `set()` function, but unfortunately the loop logic is smack in the middle of it. When the function returns, the events have already been triggered, etc.

Yes, that is my problem and that is precisely what I am trying to cleanly get around.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

Basically loop through all the attributes and `unset` properties that are invalid (falsy and non-boolean values).

```
/** Create a Model and set attributes */
var President = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var m = new President({first: 'Abraham', last: 'Lincoln', age: 90});

/** Blank out an attribute or two */
m.set({age: ''});

/** Loop through each attributes and unset falsy ones.  
    Also pass in silent = true so it doesn't trigger a change event 
       (in case you have listeners).
*/
_.each(m.toJSON(), function(val, col){
   if (typeof val !=='boolean' && !val) {
       m.unset(col, {silent: true});
   }
}, this);

/** Output the new Model */
console.log(m.toJSON());
```

**OR**

You can create a new `Model` that only contains the changed attributes if you'd rather go in that direction.

```
var President = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var m = new President({
    first: 'Abraham', last: 'Lincoln', age: 90, registered: true});

/** Blank out or change an attribute or two */
m.set({first: null});

/** Pass changed attributes to a new Model */
var t = new President();
if (!_.isEmpty(m.changedAttributes())) {
    _.each(m.changedAttributes(), function(val, col) {
        t.set(col, val);
   }, this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Dennis. Are you suggesting that what I am looking for is simply not in the design? I'm looking for a set of changes (obviously, the object I pass to `set()` in my example is that very set), and a modified resulting object (which of course I could do by hand as you did). Maybe I've just been staring at this too long. =/

Comment: There's a reason why Backbone sends the entire `Model` to the server since in most scenarios, your server expects those attributes to be present. Unless your server takes care of removing undefined or empty attributes already? Another option aside from what I posted is to override the `sync` function and perform a check similar to what I have posted.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using MongoDB as my server, and while it will accept `undefined` values, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me to store them . I'll take a look at the `sync` override. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting, in my specific case (outside the scope of this question) I won't be able to do that because my `Model`s are tied to `Marionette` `*View`s.  

I'm not looking for a hand-rolled solution though - I can _make_ it work how I want it. I'm looking for a justification of the current design for this common scenario. I will clarify my question further.  Thanks again!